# How do I find the expected value of the first random variable to have value greater than a constant?

Tags: probability, expected-value, stochastic-processes, exponential-distribution

Suppose I have a series of independent, identically distributed random variables $X_1, X_2, ...$, each of which has the exponential distribution with parameter λ.

How can I find the expected value $n$ such that $X_n$ is the first variable with value greater than or equal to some constant *Y*?

I see that the probability that the first $m$ variables do not satisfy the criteria is $(1-e^{-\lambda Y})^m$, but I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Comment: The question in the title of your question does not match the one in the text.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.

Let $1 - (1 - e^{-\lambda Y}) = e^{-\lambda Y} = x$ be the probability of success in single trial (so that $X_i \ge Y$). What is the probabilty that the first success is at position $n$? Well, it is

$$(1-x)^{n-1}x$$

Now try to express it as a random variable and calculate the expected value.

Comment: I'll give you an A on the OP's homework assignment.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Yes you are right, but thanks for the A. I eddited my answer

Comment: The OP can easily look at the edit history and see the original version. Perhaps you should delete your answer and then post a new answer.

Comment: @Mark Well, the OP can now that you told them how to do it. I don't think it's necessary to delete the answer as long as the issue is kept in mind for next time.